# Using 'not is in' in PySpark and getting an empty dataframe back

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, count, sql-in

I'm trying to use `filter` to find those 'title' that are not in `list_A`.

```py
A = B.groupBy("title").count()
A = A.filter(A['count'] > 1)
A_df = A.toPandas()
list_A = A_df['title'].values.tolist()
B.filter(~B.title.isin(list_A)).count()
```

However, I get an empty dataframe back (count is 0)

[image: not is in code]

It works well when I use 'is in':

[image: 'is in code']

Why this happened and how can I solve this?

I tried:

```py
B=B.na.drop(subset=["title"])
B.filter(~B.title.isin(list_A)).count()
print(B.filter(~B.title.isin(list_A) | B.title.isNull()).count())
```

It still returns 0.

Comment: Why do you not just do `B.groupby("title").count().where("count <= 1")`?

Comment: Actually, I need to do some further processing on B. The goal is `B.filter(((B.title.isin(list_A))&(B.journal!="Example"))|(~B.title.isin(list_A)))`. And I found that something wrong when doing "~isin".

Comment: I do not know your data but does this work? `B.groupby("journal", "title").count().where("count <= 1 or journal != 'Example'")`? In any case, I would try to avoid toPandas(), it defeats the whole purpose of Spark.

Comment: you could use a count window and flag the titles that have count > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because other "title" values are null.

```py
B = spark.createDataFrame([('x',), ('x',), (None,)], ['title'])

A = B.groupBy("title").count()
A = A.filter(A['count'] > 1)
A_df = A.toPandas()
list_A = A_df['title'].values.tolist()

print(B.filter(~B.title.isin(list_A)).count())
# 0
print(B.filter(B.title.isin(list_A)).count())
# 2
```

If you really need `list_A`, you shouldn't go to Pandas for it.

- You can either use `collect`

  ```py
  A = B.groupBy("title").count().filter(F.col('count') > 1)
  list_A = [x.title for x in A.collect()]
  print(list_A)
  # ['x', None]
  ```
- or `collect_set`

  ```py
  list_A = (B
      .groupBy("title").count()
      .groupBy((F.col('count') > 1).alias('_c')).agg(
          F.collect_set('title').alias('_t')
      ).filter('_c')
      .head()[1]
  )
  print(list_A)
  # ['x']
  ```

Finally, to translate your current query to PySpark, you should use window functions.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
B = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('x', 'Example'),
     ('x', 'Example'),
     ('x', 'not_example'),
     ('y', 'not_example'),
     (None, 'not_example'),
     (None, 'Example')],
    ['title', 'journal'])
```

Your current script:

```py
A = B.groupBy("title").count()
A = A.filter(A['count'] > 1)
A_df = A.toPandas()
list_A = A_df['title'].values.tolist()
B.filter(((B.title.isin(list_A))&(B.journal!="Example"))|(~B.title.isin(list_A)))
```

Suggestion:

```py
B_filtered = (B
    .withColumn('A_cnt', F.count('title').over(W.partitionBy('title')))
    .filter("(A_cnt > 1 and journal != 'Example') or A_cnt <= 1")
    .drop('A_cnt')
)
B_filtered.show()
# +-----+-----------+
# |title|    journal|
# +-----+-----------+
# | null|not_example|
# | null|    Example|
# |    x|not_example|
# |    y|not_example|
# +-----+-----------+
```